# How to edit multiple files at once?

Tags: files, multiple-cursors, refactoring

Is there a way to open multiple buffers that are open at the same time? 
The idea is to be able to refactor code and variable names in multiple files at once. I know that `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` exists but I was hopeing for a way where I could more clearly see what was happening.

Perhaps something related to `multi-occur`. Or allowing me to have multiple files open in one buffer and then using `multiple-cursors`.

Comment: I recommend using both `wgrep` and `multiple-cursors` -- they changed my life for the better.

Comment: Your comment led me to find that `ivy` can open an "occur" or "mult-occur" buffer and then from there I can use wgrep to edit that buffer! Thank you so much for leading me on the right track

Comment: Why do you need/want to visit the multiple files *in the same buffer*? Why not visit them in separate buffers (separate windows or separate frames)? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821) - what is it that you are really trying to do (e.g. with the multiple files)?

Comment: To edit multiple places, perhaps renaming a variable in multiple files or something of that ilk, without having to repeat that in every buffer I want to change. At the time of writing I had no exact use but it has been something that I've wanted to do in the past and I thought it was an interesting problem

Comment: Define *"more clearly see what was happening"*.

Answer (score 5):

You can give [multifiles](https://github.com/magnars/multifiles.el) a try. From its README:

> Bind a key to mf/mirror-region-in-multifile, let's say C-!. Now mark a part of the buffer and press it. A new *multifile* buffer pops up. Mark some other part of another file, and press C-! again. This is added to the *multifile*.
>
> You can now edit the *multifile* buffer, and watch the original files
>   change. Or you can edit the original files and watch the *multifile*
>   buffer change.
>
> Saving the *multifile* buffer will save all the original files.

Answer (score 1):

The [noccur](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/noccur.el) package makes it easier to edit multiple (not-necessarily opened) files with multi-occur.  After installing, this is an example of how to do a multi-occur edit:

1. `M-x noccur-project`, and provide a search regexp and directory to be searched.
2. In the multi-occur buffer that appears, type `e` to switch to edit mode.
3. Make any changes to the multi-occur buffer that you want (e.g. using `iedit-mode`), and when finished, press `C-c` to save all changes.