# How to comment or uncomment the same lines of code in multiple files at once?

Tags: files

Suppose you have multiple files which has common lines of code or common matches of a regexp pattern. Is there an "emacs way" to comment/uncomment such specific common lines at once in all files?

I know how to do it with sed or awk, but maybe there is a clever way to do this type of job directly from emacs.

Comment: You may try `helm-ag` as described [here](https://rameezkhan.me/search-and-replace-spacemacs/)

Answer (score 2):

I think functionality that comes closest to what you ask for, is provided via the [wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) package, optionally combined with some other package like [iedit](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit) or [multiple-cursors.el](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el). You can search the web for more info about how to use (the combination of) them, or otherwise the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/243/26163) might be clear enough already. Personally, I am using Spacemacs, for which I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAHVwhTsF-g&t=2s) by [Jack of Some](https://www.youtube.com/c/JackofSome) very useful.

Alternatively, the [noccur](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/noccur.el) package as mentioned in the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53096/26163) looks useful too.